# If Cell equals value AND another cell is greater then another cell

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif, array-formulas

So right now my formula is

```
=COUNTIFS(D4,"Ajay", E4,">"&F4)
```

Which seems to work fine for 1 item but doesn't seem to work as a range?

```
=COUNTIFS(D4:D50,"Ajay", E4:E50,">"&F4:F50)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: "doesn't seem to work as a range" - you mean evaluating each row or evaluating whole range ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((D4:D50="Ajay")*(E4:E50>F4:F50), 1, ))
```

[image: 0]

or the actual count of it:

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IF((D4:D50="Ajay")*(E4:E50>F4:F50), 1, )))
```

Comment: Hi player0 - it needs to be a count (for a league table)

Comment: Perfect :) Thank you so much